# All Your Base (Numbering System Conversions)

Tags: mathematics, pattern

For each of the numbering systems below, can you determine the rule for representing numbers in that system?

| Decimal | Number System 1 | Number System 2 | Number System 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 9 | 231 | 200 |
| 392 | $, | 6040 | 2003 |
| 5,236 | W+ | 83440 | 1011002 |
| 146,004 | 00t | 1380300 | 300000012 |
| 25,897,872 | >3V1 | C6345030 | 123014 |

Comment: That's a lot of text...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Number system 3:

> This system is based on prime factors.  The rightmost digit is the number of $2$s in the factorization, the next is the number of $3$s, and so on.
>
>   $$\small\begin{align}25_{10} &=& 5^2 \centerdot 3^0 \centerdot 2^0 &=& 200_{pf} &\;\;\;\text{(look at the exponents)}\\392_{10} &=& 7^2 \centerdot 5^0 \centerdot 3^0 \centerdot 2^3 &=& 2003_{pf}\\5236_{10} &=& 17^1 \centerdot 13^0 \centerdot 11^1 \centerdot 7^1 \centerdot 5^0 \centerdot 3^0 \centerdot 2^2 &=& 1011002_{pf}\\146004_{10} &=& 23^3 \centerdot 19^0 \centerdot 17^0 \centerdot 13^0 \centerdot 11^0 \centerdot 7^0 \centerdot 5^0 \centerdot 3^1 \centerdot 2^2 &=& 300000013_{pf}\\25,897,872_{10} &=& 13^1 \centerdot 11^2 \centerdot 7^3 \centerdot 5^0 \centerdot 3^1 \centerdot 2^4 &=& 123014_{pf}\\\end{align}$$

Comment: If we used this number system all the time, it would totally destroy modern cryptography, since it's based on the difficulty of factoring large numbers.  If the number is represented as the product of its fractions, factorization becomes trivial, and the cryptography is easily broken.

Comment: can you prove that? it seems to me you're saying that if I use this number system for just a moment I can break cryptography.

Comment: The problem is with the 'if'.  Try counting in that system. Try sorting lists of numbers. Simple addition would be impossible.

Comment: @Octopus I meant if everyone used it all the time. Just using it momentarily obviously does nothing.

Comment: @chasly Absolutely. I'm not saying it would be practical or feasible; it was just an interesting observation.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain - The real point I was trying to make is that even if you could somehow find a way to use this system for everyday arithmetic, cryptography would still not be broken. This is because cryptography typically uses very large semi-primes. These numbers are far bigger than the ones we use for counting--they are far bigger than the number of atoms in the known universe. Simply to write one in this number system would require you to be able break cryptography!  The next comment shows a 'small' one of these numbers written in base 10. Can you convert it to this number system?

Comment: 2140324650240744961264423072839333563008614715144755017797754920881418023447
          1401366433455190958046796109928518724709145876873962619215573630474547705208
          0511905649310668769159001975940569345745223058932597669747168173806936489469
          9871578494975937497937

Comment: Note to anyone trying. If you solve this using your own efforts then prepare to become famous!

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer ...

Number System 1:

> This is basically a base 95 number system where the value of each digit is the corresponding ASCII value minus 32.
>  $$\small\begin{array}{rrrrr}\\ &9 \rightarrow &&&&(57-32) \cdot 95^0=&25\\&\$, \rightarrow &&&(36-32) \cdot 95^1 + &(44-32) \cdot 95^0=&392\\&W+ \rightarrow &&&(87-32) \cdot 95^1 + &(43-32) \cdot 95^0=&523600\\&t \rightarrow &&(48-32) \cdot 95^2 + &(48-32) \cdot 95^1 + &(116-32) \cdot 95^0=&146004\\&>3V1 \rightarrow &(62-32) \cdot 95^3 + &(51-32) \cdot 95^2 + &(86-32) \cdot 95^1 + &(49-32) \cdot 95^0=&25897872\\\end{array}$$

Number System 2:

In this system the digits have the following values from least to most significant:

> $1^0 \space 2^1 \space 3^2 \space 4^3 \space ...$

Interpreting $C$ as $12$ similar to hexadecimal numbers this gives:

> $$\small\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}\\&&&&&&2 \cdot 3^2 + &3 \cdot 2^1 + &1 \cdot 1^0 = &25\\&&&&&6 \cdot 4^3 + &0 \cdot 3^2 + &4 \cdot 2^1 + &0 \cdot 1^0 = &392\\&&&&8 \cdot 5^4 + &3 \cdot 4^3 + &4 \cdot 3^2 + &4 \cdot 2^1 + &0 \cdot 1^0 = &5236\\&&1 \cdot 7^6 + &3 \cdot 6^5 + &8 \cdot 5^4 + &0 \cdot 4^3 + &3 \cdot 3^2 + &0 \cdot 2^1 + &0 \cdot 1^0 = &146004\\&12 \cdot 8^7 + &6 \cdot 7^6 + &3 \cdot 6^5 + &4 \cdot 5^4 + &5 \cdot 4^3 + &0 \cdot 3^2 + &3 \cdot 2^1 + &0 \cdot 1^0 = &25897872\end{array}$$